# Ursina - Moving Entities in the direction they are facing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ursina

I am trying to make a program that shoots a projectile when left mouse button clicks. I want it to have a entity spawn, point in the direction of where the mouse was when it was clicked and move in the direction it is pointing.

I tried to use the Entity.position += Entity.forward way that I read some articles about online. Heres my code:

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

def update():

    if held_keys['left mouse']:
        projectile = Entity(model = 'cube', texture = 'white_cube', color = color.white, scale = 0.5)
        projectile.look_at_2d(mouse.position)
        projectile.position += projectile.forward

app.run()
```

It would spawn the cube and turn it but it didn't move at all.
I tried using a while loop like this:

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

def update():

    if held_keys['left mouse']:
        projectile = Entity(model = 'cube', texture = 'white_cube', color = color.white, scale = 0.5)
        projectile.look_at_2d(mouse.position)
        While True:
            projectile.position += projectile.forward

app.run()
```

This would just crash the window.
I have no clue what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

since `update` gets called every frame, you're making a new projectile every frame, call look_at_2d and move it forward. Next frame you make a new one and move it forward once. This will make it seem like it's not moving, but you're actually spawning 60 entities each second.

Maybe what you want is to make one at the start and then move it during update? To do this, simply instantiate the Entity outside the update function and do the particle.look_at() and .position += particle.forward inside update.

There is one other problem I can spot though. With look_at_2d you're trying to look at mouse.position, but mouse.position is in UI space, while the entity is in 3d space (parented to scene). I'm no sure exactly what you want, but you could either parent the entity to camera.ui so they're in the same space, or you could get the world space position with mouse.world_point and look at that instead. For that you'll need to make something like a ground and add a collider to it so the mouse can figure out where it would intersect in 3d space.

Comment: I guess I didn’t clarify this in the post. I want it to work like a projectile (like a bullet or something along those lines) where when I click it spawns the entity in a defined spot, point towards the mouse and move that direction.

Comment: So I've tried out a bunch of things including the thing you said to try and even when I create the entity outside of the update() and put look_at_2d(mouse.position) and Entity.position += Entity.forward it still doesn't move at all.